# The argument type 'Future<List<PieChartSectionData>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<PieChartSectionData>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a chart that retrieve from firebase firestore but its says that

The argument type 'Future<List<PieChartSectionData>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<PieChartSectionData>?' on the line sections: showingSections();

. Here are my codes,

```
children: <Widget>[
                                      const SizedBox(height: 18),
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: AspectRatio(
                                          aspectRatio: 1,
                                          child: PieChart(
                                            PieChartData(
                                              pieTouchData: PieTouchData(
                                                touchCallback:
                                                    (FlTouchEvent event,
                                                        pieTouchResponse) {},
                                              ),
                                              borderData: FlBorderData(
                                                  //show: false,
                                                  ),
                                              sectionsSpace: 0,
                                              centerSpaceRadius: 40,
                                              sections: showingSections(), // this is the error //
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: const <Widget>[
                                          Indicator(
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                            text: 'Fiest',
                                            isSquare: true,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
```

this is my function,

```
Future<List<PieChartSectionData>> showingSections() async {
    int count = await subuhPrayedOnTime();
    int count2 = await subuhPrayedLate();
    double percentage1 = count * 0.4;
    double percentage2 = count2 * 0.10;

    return [
      PieChartSectionData(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        value: percentage1,
        title: '${percentage1.toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
        radius: 60,
        titleStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
          //shadows: shadows,
        ),
      ),
      PieChartSectionData(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        value: percentage2,
        title: '${percentage2.toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
        radius: 60,
        titleStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
          //shadows: shadows,
        ),
      ),
    ];

    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing return type of the function from

```
Future<List<PieChartSectionData>> showingSections() async {
    int count = await subuhPrayedOnTime();
    int count2 = await subuhPrayedLate();
    double percentage1 = count * 0.4;
    double percentage2 = count2 * 0.10;

    return [
      PieChartSectionData(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        value: percentage1,
        title: '${percentage1.toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
        radius: 60,
        titleStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
          //shadows: shadows,
        ),
      ),
      PieChartSectionData(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        value: percentage2,
        title: '${percentage2.toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
        radius: 60,
        titleStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
          //shadows: shadows,
        ),
      ),
    ];

    
  }
```

To

```
List<PieChartSectionData> showingSections() async {
    int count = await subuhPrayedOnTime();
    int count2 = await subuhPrayedLate();
    double percentage1 = count * 0.4;
    double percentage2 = count2 * 0.10;

    return [
      PieChartSectionData(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        value: percentage1,
        title: '${percentage1.toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
        radius: 60,
        titleStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
          //shadows: shadows,
        ),
      ),
      PieChartSectionData(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        value: percentage2,
        title: '${percentage2.toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
        radius: 60,
        titleStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
          //shadows: shadows,
        ),
      ),
    ];

    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`showingSections` is a future method, you need to await/FutureBuilder to fetch data.

For your case, create a future on state class[if stateFullWidget].

```dart
late final dFuture = showingSections();
```

and use like

```dart
Expanded(
  child: FutureBuilder<List<PieChartSectionData>>(
      future: dFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
          return AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: PieChart(
              PieChartData(
                pieTouchData: PieTouchData(
                  touchCallback:
                      (FlTouchEvent event, pieTouchResponse) {},
                ),
                borderData: FlBorderData(
                    //show: false,
                    ),
                sectionsSpace: 0,
                centerSpaceRadius: 40,
                sections: snapshot.data!, // this is the error //
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }),
),
```

Find more about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: I follow your code, but the errors on

sections: snapshot.data!,

says The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<PieChartSectionData>?'

Comment: mybad, I;ve used `<Object>`, replace it with `List<PieChartSectionData>`

Comment: what if i want to use aggregatequerysnapshot to count the data and use the count of data to display in the chart?

here are the function 

Future<int> subuhPrayedOnTime() async {
    AggregateQuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('record_prayer')
        .where('prayerName', isEqualTo: 'subuh')
        .where('dailyPrayerStatus', isEqualTo: 'Prayed On Time')
        .count()
        .get();
    return snapshot.count;
  }